# Problema api rest codeigniter às vezes sem resposta

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, libcurl

Estou usando uma api rest entre 2 aplicações diferentes, postando de uma para outras um array, porém no servidor tem momentos em que a outra api não responde. Coloquei para criar um log assim que começa a função que recebe o POST, e não chega nem a criar o log.

Alguém tem alguma noção do que pode ser? O que acho estranho é ter hora que da certo, e tem hora que não.

Comment: Como você chama a API de uma aplicação para a outra? Como é o tipo de conteúdo? Esse erro ocorre somente em um ambiente? Dê mais detalhes para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o código para que possamos analisar o problema, falando assim vagamente, não podemos ajudá-lo.